# Cannot locate zlib or pcre location after install

Tags: debian, locate, pcre

I installed zlib1g zlib1g-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev **with apt** for NGINX open source over installing zlib & pcre in their own folders. I cannot seem to locate both zlib & pcre libraries on my debian system.

Nginx requires the path to zlib & pcre to be specified when compiling.

Things I've tried:

```
which zlib1g
type zlib1g
whereis zlib1g
locate zlib1g
```

None of the commands can locate, and install either return nothing or just the name back to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dpkg -L package` to list the files installed as part of a package.